# Does Google Analytics reset UTM after transaction?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

We know that Google Analytics tracks the UTM params present on the url during all eCommerce navigation.

One thing that i cant find over the Analytics Documentation is the following:

Does google Analytics reset the UTM params after the transaction has been made?

Take the following usecase as an example:

- User clicks on Google Ads
- User enter in the website with google ads UTMs.
- User finish purchase (so Order Channel = Google Analytics)
- User forgot to buy one item
- He add the content to cart and finish the second purchase
- The second order has the same UTM from the first purchase?

][`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the traffic parameters go at session level so while the user dont end the session (no hits for 30 mins on default) or access with another traffic source on the same session the source, medium and campaign should be the same.

On the example you gave both transactions would be attributed to the same session, source, medium and campaign.

Hope it help!